# Saving the edited UITableView Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

So basically I have a table view of folder objects and I want to be able to remove/ delete folders. So far if I try to delete, the folders are removed, but when I re run the application they are all back (so the delete is not saved). Any advice?

here is my delete method for the `UITableView`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        [self.folders removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *newSavedFolders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (Folder *folder in self.folders){
            [newSavedFolders addObject:[self folderWithName:folder.name]];
        }

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

and the `folderWithName` method is from here:

```
- (Folder *)folderWithName:(NSString *)name {
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    Folder *folder = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    folder.name = name;
    folder.date = [NSDate date];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        //we have an error
    }

    return folder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it deletes is because of this line:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

That removes the row from view, but doesn't remove the data.

If your using CoreData then you simply do the following with a NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }


} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}
```

}

Add call your items with the NSFetchedResultsController this way:

```
#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number for displaying in UITableView.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```